# Using Insertion Sort on Doubly-Linked-Lists and Writing to File

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list, insertion-sort

I am working on a double linked list that will read input from a file (in.txt), store the information in a double linked list, use insertion sort to sort all the nodes in the linked list, and then print out the sorted list to a file that will be created called out.txt

The input file is formatted as:

*StudentID Firstname Lastname Department GPA* (with any amount of whitespace)

And the output file is to be formatted as:

*StudentID,Firstname,Lastname,Department,GPA* (with only commas separating the elements)

StudentID is a 7 digit integer, GPA is a float between 0 and 4, the rest are character strings. The sorting is done exclusively on the StudentID number, and no two StudentID numbers will be the same.

I have it all almost working with [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c57b7a8d66948c73af57) code:

The problem is that the output file shows nothing. I believe the problem is in my remove_node function but I am not sure. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I checked your code with two inputs like in the question, that is worked fine.

Comment: I am not getting it for some reason.  I get a blank output file. Anyone Else?

Answer (score 1):

Your insertion sort has a "remove_node" in it. Sorting should not remove any nodes.

Comment: I am only temporarily removing it so that I can put it back where it belongs.  I am trying to do an insertion sort.

Comment: But then you should have an "add_node" to "put it back in" and you don't.

Comment: but i do though.  I remove it from the list buy keep a reference to it as node.  Then i place it adjacent to where the temp pointer stops in the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
void DLList_free(List * list){
Node * node;
Node * holder;

/* see the for loop statement */
for(node = list->first; node != NULL;) 
{
    holder = node->next;
    free(node->Dept);
    free(node->Lname);
    free(node->Fname);
    free(node);
    node = holder;
}
```

}

Comment: That would seem to make sense since I would be doing the same with node=holder and then the "node = node->next".  Was this the only problem you saw?